# Oracle bi config.cmd not run in windows 10

Tags: oracle-bi

I am trying to install oracle bi on Windows 10.

I ran the install file and set weblogic and repository, but when I go to this directory:

> C:\Oracle\Middleware\Oracle_Home\bi\bin

and try to run the config.cmd, the command prompt opens and immediately closes. It doesn’t show me the setup window.

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: You could try running command prompt as administrator, don't know if that will help tbh.

Comment: @Sean my command prompt in the administrator mode

Comment: Can't help you out then, good luck solving this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Very simple solution: not trying to install OBI on an unsupported platform!

https://dimensionality.ch/2017/05/06/installing-oracle-bi-on-windows-7-8-10/

By the way the response in here will stay the same as on the Oracle communities ...

Comment: thanks for answer my fiend,means oracle bi not support windows 10?

Comment: No. Windows 10 is a *desktop* operating system. Oracle BI is a whole server farm. Not a desktop app. You need a proper server operating system.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue as you and I was to gave up but I decided I don't do it and I start to search for this problem. The first things to have to do is check your PATH JAVA_HOME. My native language is Spanish and my windows OS is in Spanish.

My JAVA_HOME was C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.8.0_181 and I have a problem to time installing so I change by  C:\Progra~2\Java\jdk1.8.0_181 then I restart my laptop and I open CMD as Admin and put cd C:\Oracle\Middleware\Oracle_Home\bi\bin because in this route was installed my OBI. After that just put  C:\Oracle\Middleware\Oracle_Home\bi\bin>config.cmd and I can continue to the configure of OBI.

1. Progra~1 = 'Program Files'
2. Progra~2 = 'Program Files(x86)'

If you forgot anything, just enter to link to refer:

http://obieeil.blogspot.com/2015/10/installing-obiee-12c-on-my-windows.html

or

http://www.catgovind.com/obiee/step-by-step-obiee-12c-installation-on-windows-oracle-bi-publisher-installation-and-oracle-bi-analytic-installation/